# Azure DSC extension: Is it possible to pass a secure parameter to the xPackage Arguments value?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, dsc

I'm trying using Azure DSC to pass a encrypted parameter to xpackage like so

azureDeploy.json

```
"parameters": {
  "appPassword": {
    "type": "securestring",
  },
}
...
"resources": [
{
  "type": "extensions",
  "name": "DSC",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",

  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",

    "protectedSettings": {
      "appPassword": "[parameters('appPassword')]",
      "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]",
      "artifactsLocationSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
    }
  }
```

configuration.ps1

```
Configuration vm
{
param (
appPassword
)
...
xPackage app
{
...
Arguments = "/S /v`"/qn ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD=$appPassword`""
}
```

However when I do this, the "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD" value is not set to parameter. If I passed the same parameter under settings it works.

Comment: I assume it is `param (
$appPassword
)` not `param (
appPassword
)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Azure DSC Extension JSON blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/26/arm-dsc-extension-settings/)

The corrected JSON would be:

```
"parameters": {
  "appPassword": {
    "type": "securestring",
  },
}
...
"resources": [
{
  "type": "extensions",
  "name": "DSC",
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",

  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",

    "protectedSettings": {
      "configurationArguments": {
          "appPassword": "[parameters('appPassword')]"
      },
      "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]",
      "artifactsLocationSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
    }
  }
```

**Note**, I haven't had time to test this.  I reviewed the code and it looks like this should work.